# How to show .js file under .ts file in VS Code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, web-frontend

I am using VS Code for an application in which I am using Reactjs and TypeScript. I have used

```
create-react-app-typescript
```

as a template to set up my project. Now when I run the build task from VS Code, I can see a build folder and the generated js files there as well as the generated source files.

I am wondering if I can see generated .js file under its .ts version in VS Code - like you can see those together in Visual Studio ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a tsconfig file in my application's folder, in which

```
"outDir": "build/dist"
```

was causing generated files to go into build/dist folder. Removing this for tsconfig.json file will place generated files along with original .ts files in VS Code.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a VSCode Typescript user. I've never seen that feature is available in VSCode. One thing that I usually do is to hide its javascript files on the sidebar.

```
{
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/.git": true,
        "**/.DS_Store": true,
        "**/*.js": {"when": "$(basename).ts"}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For anybody who finds this:
There is (now) a built-in setting `Explorer > File Nesting` which does exactly this. You can also configure the pattern of nesting under `Explorer > File Nesting: Patterns`